# Not able to see the sandbox option under setup

Tags: sandbox, setup

I am  trying to create a sandbox from trial org but I am not able to get the sandbox option as mentioned  in the document

To create a new sandbox:
    From Setup, click Sandboxes or Data Management | Sandboxes.
    Click New Sandbox.
    Enter a name and description for the sandbox.

I am the system admin of the org any missing configuration?

Comment: Is sandboxes entirely missing from your setup menu, or are there no available sandboxes to create ?

Comment: Is it possible at all in trial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In looking at that [Managing Sandboxes help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_manage.htm&language=en), there are a few possible causes:

1. Are you in production?  You can only see the Sandboxes if you are logged into production.
2. Do you have one of the following editions: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Database.com Editions?  Sandboxes are only available for those editions. For example, if you have a Professional Edition trial then you won't have sandboxes.
3. Do you have the “View Setup and Configuration” and “Modify All Permissions” User Permissions?

Comment: I am in production which is in trial

Comment: Is the edition of your org one of the ones I have listed in point #2 in my answer? Is it possible you have a trial of an edition that doesn't support sandboxes (e.g., Professional)?  If you actually have a Developer Edition as opposed to a trial org, you definitely will not have the Sandbox option.

Comment: I got the reason it was professional edition. Thanks alot

Comment: @ShebinMathew Sure!  Glad to help. :)